# Audio is not working in 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04, input

this is my situation:
With Mint 17.3 Mate I have the audio card (on the motherboard) recognized and perfectly configurated, Output via HDMI, and Input via HDMI. (Audacity just record what the tv plays).
With Ubuntu 16.04 I Have only Output OK via HDMI but no input device found.

I've tried to install Ubuntu desktop on Mint 17.3, and I have the same problem: accessing with Ubuntu desktop means no input device.

Any solution?
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is a problem with drivers,.. or rather see this link https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html

An Ubuntu documentation.